# Pod Affinity for a specific Namespace in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to deploy my pods in a specific namespace. I think about Pod Affinity but can't find a solution on how to select specific namespace.
Does anybody do it?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more what you're trying to do?  You can deploy pods in a specific namespace, most easily by using the `kubectl apply -n` option to specify which namespace, but that doesn't have any effect on what node they run on.

Answer (score 7):

As part of Anti-Affinity you can provide `namespaceSelector: {}` to allow the `labelSelector` to match labels on pods from all namespaces instead of the pod's own namespace only.

The comment in the source code about the NamespaceSelector:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/287888b191968198679159580b1bb76b529aa8c0/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go#L2927

Example

```yaml
          affinity:
            podAntiAffinity:
              preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                - weight: 100
                  podAffinityTerm:
                    labelSelector:
                      matchExpressions:
                        - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                          operator: In
                          values:
                            - foobar
                    topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
                    namespaceSelector: {}
```

EDIT:
The namespaceSelctor for pod affinity is in Alpha v1.21

Feature disscusion: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68827

Comment: To quote the comment in the source code: null or empty namespaces list and null namespaceSelector means "this pod's namespace" (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go#L2792). So this has to be done via the namespaceSelector because: "An empty selector ({}) matches all namespaces." (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go#L2805)

Comment: To be clear to future searchers, the default when not setting `namespaces` or `namespaceSelector` will be that your affinity rule only checks against your current namespace. For example, if you set a `podAntiAffinity` to check that Pods in your StatefulSet labeled `app: Kafka` are spread between Nodes with different values for `kubernetes.io/hostname`, that would only check for pods with the `app: Kafka` label in the current namespace. Your Pods would not be forced to different Nodes because someone made an identical setup in another Namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Pod anti-affinity is about telling Kubernetes to schedule (run) this pod X in a node (machine) **far away** than nodes running other pods Y.

So :

- What's X ?
- What's Y ?
- What's the criterion of "far away" ?

See this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-x
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: y-key
              operator: In
              values:
              - y-value
          topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
```

In this example :

- X is pod-x
- Y is any pod has label (y-key=y-value)
- "Far away" criteria is `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone`

If this is clear, you will see that namespaces are nothing to do with anti-affinity or even affinity.

looking into [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) is a good practice also .